# Proving that $\bar{ \bar {A}} \subset \bar {A}$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I want only to check my proof for an exam, and hope anybody can correct what's wrong. I know there's a similar one or maybe of the same idea, but in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1211248/show-that-bar-bara-bara), the asker had no formal proof to be checked, hope mine will not be closed as duplicate.

Take $x \in \bar{ \bar {A}}$,

$\Rightarrow$ for every $\epsilon_x >0$, $B(x, \epsilon_x)$ $\cap \bar{A} \neq \emptyset$

$\Rightarrow$ $\exists y$; $y \in \bar{A}$ and $ y\in B(x, \epsilon_x)$

$\Rightarrow$ $y \in \bar{A}$ and $\exists \epsilon_y$; $B(y, \epsilon_y)$ $\subset B(x, \epsilon_x)$

$\Rightarrow$ $B(y, \epsilon_y)$ $\cap A \neq \emptyset$ and  $B(y, \epsilon_y)$ $\subset$ $B(x, \epsilon_x)$

$\Rightarrow$ $B(x, \epsilon_x)$ $\cap A \neq \emptyset$

$\Rightarrow$ $x \in \bar{A}$.

Comment: $\overline{A}$ is a closed set so its closure is equal to itself.

Comment: We cant assume A is in a metric space unless this is given in the problem

Comment: $\bar A $ is closed;   therefore contains all its limit points. ..

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to prove that, in any topological space, $\overline{\overline A}\subset\overline A$. But your proof can only work in metric spaces, since you use a distance. If you meant to prove it on metric spaces only, you should have said so and used the `metric-spaces` tag. Other than that, your proof is a but clumsy, but the idea is correct,